# Simulate some correlated variables, each with a given one-period autocorrelation coefficient

Tags: r, correlation, simulation, autocorrelation

I think this question would be easy for some of you but I'm struggling to find an answer. I've looked across so many threads that I now feel info-drunk, as nothing quite helps enough.

Basically, I'm trying to run a simulation of, say, 10,000 trials for three financial series. As much for context as anything else, if all three series lack autocorrelation then I would resort to my usual approach of the *Iman and Conover* method, as shown in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5679114/using-r-to-honor-correlations-for-latinhypercube-monte-carlo-trials).

Just copying the code from the helpful answer, we have:

```
require(mc2d)
x1 <- rnorm(1000)
x2 <- rnorm(1000)
x3 <- rnorm(1000)
mat <- cbind(x1, x2, x3)

## Target
(corr <- matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.2, 0.5, 1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 1), ncol=3))
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.5  0.2
[2,]  0.5  1.0  0.2
[3,]  0.2  0.2  1.0

## Before
cor(mat, method="spearman")
            x1         x2          x3
x1  1.00000000 0.01218894 -0.02203357
x2  0.01218894 1.00000000  0.02298695
x3 -0.02203357 0.02298695  1.00000000

matc <- cornode(mat, target=corr, result=TRUE)
Spearman Rank Correlation Post Function
          x1        x2        x3
x1 1.0000000 0.4515535 0.1739153
x2 0.4515535 1.0000000 0.1646381
x3 0.1739153 0.1646381 1.0000000
```

(This functionality also generates the trials in question.)

However, in my current case, I would like to have some autocorrelation in the trials. To keep it simple, I'll assume the same contemporaneous correlations as above, but also seek each of the three variables to have a one-period autocorrelation of (say) -0.2. In other words, that there's a little mean-reversion occurring in each series.

And again, to keep it simple, I'll assume that I'm only interested in two periods: this period and the next. So, what I'm seeking to do is to generate a 10,000*2 matrix of trials for each of the three series.

**Does anybody know a way to do this?** (Your answer needn't have anything to do with R or *Iman and Conover*.)

As always, many thanks to you all for your generous assistance.

Comment: Does the Iman Conover method have to come into what you're asking for? If not, is it needed here at all?

Comment: Thanks, @Glen_b: I was using the Iman Conover method more as context, in order to explain my problem. **Any** way that can answer the question would be welcomed, with or without Iman Conover.

Comment: And I've added a clause in the question above to reflect this point

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some ideas to start with (neither tested nor rigorously thought about: someone can jump up if they see a problem with this, and if it's bad enough I'll delete it). Assuming for now that all the marginal distributions are going to be $N(0,1)$ to keep life simple ...

1. generate autocorrelated sequences by the method of your choice (if I wanted an autocorrelation coefficient of 0.2 I would just do something like

```
x <- numeric(100)
x[1] <- 1
for (i in 2:100) x[i] <- 0.2*x[i-1]+rnorm(1)
```

2. at any given time $t$ the values of these sequences are independent $N(0,1)$ variables. Transform them to correlated MVN variables by doing appropriate linear algebra: for example, the guts of `MASS:mvrnorm` use this code, where `mu` is the desired mean vector (by column) and `Sigma` is the desired variance-covariance matrix.

```
eS <- eigen(Sigma, symmetric = TRUE)
ev <- eS$values
## replace this line with cbind(<your autocorrelated vectors>)
X <- matrix(rnorm(p * n), n)
X <- drop(mu) + eS$vectors %*% diag(sqrt(pmax(ev, 0)), p) %*% 
    t(X)
```

This doesn't *quite* work because mixing the variables will slightly lower the autocorrelation (part of $x_{i,t}$ will depend on $x_{j,t-1}$ rather than $x_{i,t-1}$; you could probably do the linear algebra to correct for this ... it will also get a little messy if the different sequences have different autocorrelations.

You could alternately do this in the other order (generate correlated independent sequences of disturbances, then simulate autoregressive process with them as input).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ben for his accepted answer, I was able to resolve this question. I thought that I'd add my final code so that others might benefit from it in the future.

I begin with the settings:

```
library(mc2d)
set.seed(3)

corCoeff <- matrix(
  c(1, -0.1, 0.2, -0.1, 
    -0.1, 1, -0.1, -0.2, 
    0.2, -0.1, 1, -0.1, 
    -0.1, -0.2, -0.1, 1), 
  4)

rho <- -0.2
average <- 0.0219
vol <- 0.103
runs <- 100000

covCoeff <- as.vector(vol * corCoeff * vol)
```

I then took Ben's advice in his final sentence and generated correlated independent sequences, before simulating an auto-regressive process with them as an input. (Note the adjusted mean in df2.)

```
df1 <- as.data.frame(
  rmultinormal(n = runs, 
               mean = rep(average, 4), 
               sigma = covCoeff)
  )

df2 <- as.data.frame(
  rmultinormal(n = runs, 
               mean = rep(average*(1-rho), 4), 
               sigma = covCoeff)
  )

df3 <- df2 + (rho * df1)
```

All that gave me the desired correlation structure:

```
> cor(df1, df1)
            V1          V2          V3          V4
V1  1.00000000 -0.09795424  0.19773226 -0.10569672
V2 -0.09795424  1.00000000 -0.09404262 -0.19821460
V3  0.19773226 -0.09404262  1.00000000 -0.09762979
V4 -0.10569672 -0.19821460 -0.09762979  1.00000000

> cor(df3, df3)
           V1         V2          V3          V4
V1  1.0000000 -0.1012561  0.19985144 -0.10164954
V2 -0.1012561  1.0000000 -0.10141362 -0.19881465
V3  0.1998514 -0.1014136  1.00000000 -0.09726941
V4 -0.1016495 -0.1988147 -0.09726941  1.00000000

> cor(df1, df3)
            V1          V2          V3          V4
V1 -0.19639550  0.02111048 -0.04362043  0.02262732
V2  0.01315877 -0.19825713  0.01405789  0.04003157
V3 -0.03947411  0.02598555 -0.19348550  0.01487951
V4  0.02277597  0.03802356  0.02186739 -0.19185710
```

It also gave me the means and standard deviations that I sought:

```
> apply(df1, 2, "mean")
        V1         V2         V3         V4 
0.02207308 0.02120551 0.02241687 0.02203084 

> apply(df1, 2, "sd")
       V1        V2        V3        V4 
0.1027331 0.1030169 0.1032950 0.1032165 

> apply(df3, 2, "mean")
        V1         V2         V3         V4 
0.02162543 0.02261344 0.02153406 0.02192688 

> apply(df3, 2, "sd")
       V1        V2        V3        V4 
0.1051483 0.1055557 0.1054869 0.1053712
```

Thanks again, Ben!